# Picasso + Recyclerview

Tags: java, android

In my recyclerview I want to display images from picasso. This is my code:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder NewsViewHolder, int i) {
    NewsViewHolder.appsNaam.setText(apps.get(i).naam);
    NewsViewHolder.appsStars.setText(apps.get(i).stars);
    Picasso.with(Apps_Adapter).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(appsImage);
}
```

And these are my errors:

- "Expression expected" for Apps_Adapter
- "Can not receive symbol 'appsImage'" but I have initialized it.

Code for initialized:

`appsImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_icon);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to `with()` needs to be a `Context`, such as your `Activity`.

`appsImage` needs to be part of your `NewsViewHolder`, so `into()` would be `into(NewsViewHolder.appsImage)`.

Comment: Hi it works for the last part of my code but for the Context it says "with * it cannot be applied to *". I entered "this" for it. What should I do

Comment: @Albert-Jan: Call `getContext()` on any of your widgets, such as ``NewsViewHolder.appsImage`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder NewsViewHolder, int i) {
    NewsViewHolder.appsNaam.setText(apps.get(i).naam);
    NewsViewHolder.appsStars.setText(apps.get(i).stars);
    Picasso.with(Context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(appsImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a context, I don't know if Apps_Adapter is a context object.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder NewsViewHolder, int i) {
    NewsViewHolder.appsNaam.setText(apps.get(i).naam);
    NewsViewHolder.appsStars.setText(apps.get(i).stars);
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(NewsViewHolder.appsImage);
}
```